# jdbc Communications link failure since mariadb 10.0

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I switched from mysql to mariadb 10.0 on a ubuntu 1204 system. Since this day I often get communication link failures with java apps. As I did not have these before and according to the "differences between mysql/mariadb" article of the mariadb doc there shouldn't be any difference. I also checked the syslog and mariadb logs, there is nothing related to communication errors or timeouts. :(

I hope you have any idea what this could be as I'm quite sure that I'm not the only one using mariadb with jdbc. I'm happy about any of your thoughts of what it could be.

Thanks and an example stacktrace below:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 625,694 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor416.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2968)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1474)
    at me.raum.et.EasyTickets.queryDB(EasyTickets.java:1514)
    at me.raum.et.EasyTickets.ticketReminder(EasyTickets.java:305)
    at me.raum.et.EasyTickets$1.run(EasyTickets.java:60)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:58)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:345)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:818)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:330)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:773)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:655)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadMinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:583)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Try disabling your software firewall on the Ubuntu system temporarily.